# In java age calculate returns wrong value

Tags: java, jodatime

> In java I want to calculate age..

I am using **"jodatime.jar"**

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
LocalDate birthdate = new LocalDate ("1990-12-12");
Years age = Years.yearsBetween(birthdate, today);
```

I want age as `integer`..here it returns value like **P25Y**..How to get integer value of age..I want just **25**

Is there any other way to get age in java with date format..In google I have tried a lot but not found any proper example which use **date format**

Comment: http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Period.html#getYears()

Comment: `age.getYears()` ? from the doc _Gets the number of years that this period represents._

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `age.getYears()` to get the `int` value of age.

Answer (score 5):

**Using joda-time**

You can use [Period](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Period.html) to achieve this available in `joda time` api. Try something like this:

```
Period period = new Period(d1, d2);// d1,d2 are Date objects
System.out.print("You are " + period.getYears() + " years old");
```

**Using java.time**

If you can go Java 8 or later with the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) and [`Period`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html), then it can be achieved like this:

```
        LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
        LocalDate birthday = LocalDate.of(1990, Month.DECEMBER, 12);

        Period p = Period.between(birthday, today);
        System.out.println("You are " + p.getYears() + " years old");
```

Output

```
You are 25 years old
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `age.getYears()`. From the [doc](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Years.html#getYears())

> Gets the number of years that this period represents.

Answer (score 0):

`age` is not an `Integer` but a `Years`. If you want to retrieve the age as an integer, use the `getYears()` method:

```
int age = Years.yearsBetween(birthdate, today).getYears();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep yousing jodattime, you should know, it has a method for getting the number of year: `.getYears()`

If you just want to get the age then use Gregorian calendar to get the year and compare it to the current one:

```
Calendar date = new GregorianCalendar(2012, 9, 5);
int birthyear = date.get(Calendar.YEAR); // 2012
Date currdate = new Date();
Calendar date2 = new GregorianCalendar();
date2.setTime(currdate);
int curryear = date.2get(Calendar.YEAR); // current year(2015 atm)
```